# What is the meaning of "coarse hand"?

Tags: meaning, expressions

Recently I came across the expression "coarse hand" and couldn't find its meaning. For example,

> — Can you read?
>   — No, only coarse hand.

What does this mean?

**Edit**

This is a term Twain used in *The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn*

> I was a good deal astonished, but when I got my breath I asked her what the paper was about, and she asked me if I had read it, and I said no, and she asked me if I could read writing, and I told her "no, only **coarse-hand**," and then she said the paper warn't anything but a book-mark to keep her place, and I might go and play now.

Comment: If you do not give the full citation, it will be impossible to say.  Also, I am quite certain both *coarse* and *hand* are in every imaginable dictionary, so I do not see how you failed to find them.  Lastly, why have you capitalized *Coarse*? Is it a proper noun, like the hand of Mr Coarse?

Comment: "Recently you came across one word..." Which word are you talking about? _Coarse_? or _hand_?

Comment: @J.R.- Coarse hand completely. How can I address this 2 word?

Comment: @ColinFine - This I got from 'The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn'. Only this much is written.

Comment: If it's two words, you'd call it a "phrase", not a "word". Also, there is much more in Huck Finn than that one sentence. Giving the source helped Colin unlock the mystery, but you could have quoted a longer excerpt to provide more context. In the future, I'd recommend putting that information into the question itself (as opposed to in a subsequent comment); I allude to why [here](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3490/asking-questions-about-synonyms/3494#3494), under the section entitled "One Last Tidbit of Advice".

Comment: A proper citation includes naming the source.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the context: cite your source and give more text preceding the text in question. Also please show the results of research you are expected to do before asking here.

Comment: From the responses and down voting I felt like asking this question here was a mistake.

Comment: @Inquisitive: The basic question is a good one, but the way you phrased it at first (before the improvements) wasn’t very clear or helpful to would-be answerers, whence the downvotes.  [The FAQ](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq) has helpful guidelines for writing good questions — if you stick around, have a glance over them, and follow their advice to fly downvote-free!

Comment: @Inquisitive: Nope, not a mistake. I'd call it _coaching_ – we were trying to be helpful by teaching you how to write better questions that would be more well-received. P.S. I noticed the downvote trend has reversed since your latest edit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The phrase was completely unknown to me, as I suspect it is to anybody who has not encountered it in *The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn*.

Googling for "coarse-hand" gives [this](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDcQFjAA&url=http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110726175029AA7DEYw&ei=RdHeUMXmGYfL0AXkzIDIBQ&usg=AFQjCNFGqJajAm6cSJdtvdJvmq1CGgjujQ&sig2=6pVQ2jpAVAsS6XSipILEtQ&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.d2k) as the first result: "Coarse hand means printing as opposed to cursive writing, in which the letters are connected."

This explanation seems to make sense, but I have not found it in any dictionary; so this was a reasonable question but **only when you gave us the source**.

Comment: I immediately thought of "rough hand" or "long hand" (and of course, "short hand"), but "coarse hand" didn't even cross my mind until Huck Finn was mentioned. Your bold font closing sentence is most appropriate!

Comment: I have heard "a fine hand" in reference to handwriting but thought it just meant the letters were small and neat. Could one of these be backformed from the other?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps OP should switch to reading the [Barnes and Noble Classic Edition](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=RXfGFBatv1kC&pg=PA113&dq=%22only%20coarse%20hand%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=bivfUNbIO8eZ0QXoxIGACw&ved=0CDwQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22only%20coarse%20hand%22&f=false), which has an asterisk after the word *"hand"*, and a footnote at the bottom of the page reading...

> *Hand-printing in block letters, as opposed to cursive writing.

Answer (score -1):

I think that in the mentiones context , "reading coarse-hand" could mean reading with difficulties and mistakes.